# Why doesn't work the PlayerVars with the YouTube API anymore?

Tags: api, youtube

I posted the YouTube API and a video on my site a few days ago. I have set some PlayerVars. Everything worked then. Unfortunately, I noticed today that the player is not working properly anymore. All the PlayerVars are set in the iframe link, but they will not be executed (for example, 'showinfo': 0 will still display the video info). What can this be? Even if I remove all the changes I made since putting the video online, it will not work properly again.

HTML:

```
<div id="aboutVideoVideo"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('aboutVideoVideo', {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        videoId: 'xxx_xx',
        playerVars: {
            'showinfo': 0,
            'disablekb': 1,
            'fs': 0,
            'iv_load_policy': 3,
            'modestbranding': 1,
            'rel': 0
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    event.target.pauseVideo();
    event.target.unMute();
}
```

iframe result:

```
<iframe id="aboutVideoVideo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" title="YouTube video player" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxx_xx?showinfo=0&amp;disablekb=1&amp;fs=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx&amp;widgetid=1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

There has been a recent change in the Youtube embed API. [`Showinfo` parameter has been depreciated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#showinfo). The video title, avatar, watch later and share icons will be displayed on loading, mouseover and when paused. So `showinfo=0` doesn't work anymore.

There's also a change in the `rel` parameter.

Comment: I just noticed that this is only in the English post. However, it worked a few days ago. According to the post, the change has been there for a month. Has the change come later or why is that?
And besides, for example, controls: 0 does not work too. That should not have been changed, right?